# Expression 'return length as Int.toString' of type 'Nothing' cannot be invoked as a function

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
private String getFileSize(long length) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("######0.0");
    if (length < 1024.f) {
        return (int) length + " B";
    } else if (length < 1024 * 1024.f) {
        return df.format(length / 1024.f) + " KB";
    } else if (length < 1024 * 1024 * 1024.f) {
        return df.format((length / 1024.f / 1024.f)) + " MB";
    }
    return df.format(length / 1024.f / 1024.f / 1024.f) + " GB";
}
```

Original Code

```
private fun getFileSize(length: Long): String {
    val df = DecimalFormat("######0.0")
    if (length < 1024f) {
        return length as Int.toString() + " B"
    } else if (length < 1024 * 1024f) {
        return df.format(length / 1024f.toDouble()) + " KB"
    } else if (length < 1024 * 1024 * 1024f) {
        return df.format((length / 1024f / 1024f).toDouble()) + " MB"
    }
    return df.format(length / 1024f / 1024f / 1024f.toDouble()) + " GB"
}
```

Code After Java to Kotlin Converstion

```
return length as Int.toString() + " B"
```

Error: Expression 'return length as Int.toString' of type 'Nothing' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found. Unresolved reference: toString.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Int.toString` method as `datatype.toString` method that does not achieve anything so instead use `String` interpolations as

```
return "$length B"
```

or use `toString` as

```
return length.toString() + " B"
```

You can also use expressions with string interpolation inside `${expression}` as

```
return "${df.format(length / 1024.f)} KB";
```